# Query expression with aws policy query

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli, jmespath

Getting response back from AWS CLI call:

```
aws sns get-topic-attributes --query 'Attributes.Policy'
```

gives me the whole policy.

I would like to query specifically on one policy statement, by value of the Sid.

I Have tried:

- `` --query "[Attributes.Policy [?Statement.Sid==`mySid`]" ``
- `` --query "[Attributes.Policy.Statement [?Sid==`mySid`]" ``
- `--query="(Attributes.Policy.Statement[?Sid=='mySid'])"`

and various other fruitless attempts.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Policy is a string (albeit with a JSON string inside it). Suspect that you can't interrogate it the way you want (by parsing the JSON string and then filtering on Sid). Maybe you could leverage `jq` after the fact.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [JMESPath - parse raw string as object](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49827825/jmespath-parse-raw-string-as-object)

Comment: Thanks for the tip, I will try that.  I used 'sed' instead and it gave me a bit like what I wanted, but wouldn't mind something less janky.